# Keydetection in javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to do key detection for my game, the code I have here somewhat works, but the problem is that it doesn't allow me to press multiple keys at once, which I need for my game. It only allows one key to be pressed at any moment and moves the ball to that direction.

Is there a way to allow multiple keypresses at once?

```
var key = 0;
var pos = false;
var posX = 0;
var posY = 0;
var jumpSpeed = 4;
var ball = new Image();
ball.src = 'Ball.png';
var canvas = document.getElementById('bg');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
        pos = true;
        key = window.event ? e.keyCode : e.which;
}

document.onkeyup = function (e) {
        pos = false;
}

setInterval(function () {
    if (pos == false) return;
    else if (key == 65) posX -= 2;
    else if (key == 87) posY -= jumpSpeed;
    else if (key == 68) posX += 2;
}, 1);

setInterval(function () {
    ctx.drawImage(ball, posX, posY);
}, 1);
```

Comment: So what `key` value you have when you press multiple buttons? Maybe you need intermediate actions to be performed too? Also use single `setInterval` or even try to incorporate it to event callback

Comment: @Justinas When I press e.g. W and D at the same time it only picks one of the values, I think that it's what I pressed first.

Comment: @Justinas I have two set intervals because the other one is used for drawing all images, I didn't include all of them in this code because I didn't feel like it's relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal that your code can only process one key, since the variable `key` can only have one key code. Whenever you assign a new value to it, the previous one is overwritten.

One solution is to use a `Set` of key codes:

```
var keys = new Set;

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    keys.add(window.event ? e.keyCode : e.which);
}

document.onkeyup = function (e) {
    keys.delete(window.event ? e.keyCode : e.which);
}

setInterval(function () {
    if (keys.has(65)) posX -= 2;
    if (keys.has(87)) posY -= jumpSpeed;
    if (keys.has(68)) posX += 2;
}, 1);
```

NB: Please make sure to read the deprecation note on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode), and stop using `keyCode` or `which`. Instead use [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code).

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for